# Getting INVALID_REFRESH_TOKEN when trying to update ID (bearer) Token from Firebase for FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on an iOS app that allows device-to-device messaging without needing to be on the same network. I don't have any kind of login system, just the device ID token. The app is working fine with FCM, but when the access token (aka id Token or Bearer token) expires after an hour, I want to get a new one.

[Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api) says that I should be able to use `securetoken.googleapis.com` which I'm doing.

The API token comes from the GoogleService-Info.plist file.

The Refresh token comes from the OAuth 2.0 Playground.

I'm currently using curl for quick testing at the moment instead of Postman or Swift.

```
curl 'https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=AI_REDACTED_2o' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=1//F0_REDACTED_bmI0'
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_REFRESH_TOKEN",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I thought maybe I had to change the // characters to %2F but that didn't work. I'm at a loss as to what to do here, because the docs say that the error happens because the token is actually invalid, but it works in OAuth 2.0 Playground.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out the problem.

First, my fault, I didn't realize I had to put in the OAuth info before I selected the API I wanted to use. For some reason I had it in my head that the Authorization Code was for my account, not for my own OAuth credentials. So, click the gear on the upper-right, put in your OAuth info, THEN select the API. After that, everything fell into place.